# How to reset my input field after I submit form using pure React.js Hooks, no libraries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to reset my input field after I submit the form using only React.js, using hooks from React itself.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const Searchbar = (props) => {

    const { updateSelectedCity } = props;
    const [newCity, setCity] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setCity(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateSelectedCity(newCity);
        console.log(newCity);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input name="cityName" placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange} />
                <button type="submit">Check Weather</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Searchbar;
```

What do I need to add in order to accomplish that? Do I need to use useEffect? Or is there any way I can do it without using external libraries?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `<input>` to get its value from state:

```
<input name="cityName" placeholder={placeholder} onChange={handleChange} value={newCity} />
```

And just update state after handling the submit event:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateSelectedCity(newCity);
    console.log(newCity);
    setCity("");    //   <--- here
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion. I tried that and it doesn't work. I ended up  using this line of code instead of the one you suggested:

```
e.target.reset()
```
That line of code worked perfectly and doesn't affect my code or the functionality of my app :)